# How do I handle my character being dragon riders?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons

I'm currently playing a game of 3.5e where the PCs are to become dragon riders. We have 2 rangers, a wizard, a sorceress, a sword sage, and a rogue. They will find an elder dragon's claw that will allow their dragons to hatch and grow quicker than normal but still remain intelligent. So I guess I'm asking, do I have them just use their dragons as "companions" for about 8-10 levels and then let them eventually use them as mounts but not let them grow past that age? If you have already managed to run such a scenario, how did you handle it?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! I slightly edited the end of your question as I think it would better suit the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/what-questions-are-subjective-and-what-does-good-subjective-bad-subjective) principle of this website. If you think the edit doesn't keep  the spirit of your question, feel free to edit it back!

Answer (score 7):

There is an extensive amount of advice for GM's detailed in the Draconomicon.

Dragons are intelligent, highly intelligent. Dragons should be handled as NPC's and being respected as any other highly sentient creature should be. Being treated as an animal companion would belittle their status as not only dragons, but their intelligence as well.

Dragons being used as mounts are also covered in the Draconomicon, and there is a dragon rider prestige class in the Dragonlance source material.

Basically, dragons should be regarded as cohorts, mechanically, and in theory.

Comment: Also, Races of the Dragon and Dragon Magic are good supplemental sources - but of course for riders Draconomicon is hard foundation.